# How can I aggregate metrics per day in a Grafana - Youse table or metric?

Tags: ruby, metrics, grafana

I would add a Metric in use Grafana, in a ruby project.
What are the parameters?, What gem can I use? 
Are there a manual?

Answer (score 0):

You should first look into Datasources for Grafana. http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/ Datasources are the Programs Grafana can interact with to generate a Graph so you need to install one of them on some device. **Grafana itself does not store any data, it "just" creates queries to a Datasource and renders the data**.

There are a lot of possible Datasources for Grafana as you can see. Commonly used are Graphite (my favourite) and InfluxDB (easy setup) but a standard SQL could also be the way to go for you. When researching the possible Datasources you can also search for Ruby Gems. I found one for InfluxDB, maintained by Influxdata itself https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-ruby